# "git svn fetch" fails, ls-tree dying because of missing tree object

Tags: svn, git, tags, fetch

"git svn fetch" does not finish and spews out the following (error) messages:

```
(dev) martinom :: /var/my/git ‹master*› » git svn fetch
Found possible branch point: http://.../branches/dexter/lib => http://.../tags/dexter-17, 25032
Initializing parent: refs/remotes/tags/dexter-17@25032 branch_from: /.../trunk => /.../trunk/lib
Found possible branch point: http://.../trunk/lib => http://.../branches/dexter/lib, 24233
Initializing parent: refs/remotes/tags/dexter-17@24233
fatal: Not a valid object name 
ls-tree -z  ./: command returned error: 128
```

It seems like ls-tree is missing the object name before the path there. I don't know in which context this is called and why it's not there.

A bit of background might help illuminate whats wrong:

1. I was supposed to create a tag from the entire repository in tags/, however, I managed to only copy branches/.../lib to tags, creating a broken tag (svn cp ...).
2. I then removed the broken tag (dexter-17) with svn rm.
3. I created the new proper tag with yet another call to cp.

Then normal development was continued and all seemed well. Well, up until I tried to update my git-svn repository.

I guess there might be several ways to bypass this issue. Firstly, you can see that the history is getting quite large, we're passed 25k revisions, so cloning with git from a rev past the broken revisions is the least desirable.

Somehow skipping the tag creation revisions in git-svn is another, if it's possible. I don't really need the history for the broken tag in history.

Finally, perhaps removing/fixing things in the subversion repository/db to make it compatible with git-svn. If this means removing the revision entirely or modifying it or something.

It would be great to also know what is actually causing git-svn to barf like this. From .git/svn/refs/remotes/tags I see dexter-17, dexter-17@2423 and dexter-17@25032 as remote refs.. That doesn't seem quite sane to me...

Answer (score 0):

I have been successful running "git svn rebase" to update my git repository with the latest updates to SVN.  Have you tried rebase?